# This should be an easy one : Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Why would Grandpa chose these folks?

> Grandpa likes Mozart but not Tchaikovsky
>
> Grandpa likes Queen Victoria but not Mary, Queen of Scots
>
> Grandpa likes Gandhi but not Mandela

Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grandpa is short so he likes short people

Comment: Nobody knows for sure how tall Tchaikovsky was, apparently...(but the others I definitely agree with)

Comment: Accept this answer, @DEEM. It would be helpful to see the question as answered and not *unanswered*.

Answer (score 6):

Since the answer is not

> people with 8 letters in their first name,

Could Grandpa like...

> Major Civilization 6 characters?

He likes

> [Mozart](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart_(Civ6)) but not Tchaikovsky

He likes

> [Queen Victoria](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_(Civ6)) but not Mary, Queen of Scots

He likes

> [Gandhi](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Gandhi_(Civ6)) but not Mandela

Comment: Wow. Great catch but Grandpa has another reason

Answer (score 3):

Grandpa likes

> people commonly referred to with first names that is not their real first name

Mozart:

> Born: Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart
>  Commonly called: Wolfgang Mozart

Ghandi:

> Born: Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi
> Commonly Called: Mahatma Gandhi

Queen Victoria:

> Born: Alexandrina Victoria
> Commonly Called: Victoria

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Grandpa likes those who came before. 
>   Grandpa likes Mozart but not Tchaikovsky who was inspired by Mozart
>  He likes Victoria but not Mary, Queen of Scots who was her descendant
> He likes Gandhi but not Mandela who was inspired by him.